# Keep footer down with semi transparent background

Tags: html, css

I've looked at every page for this problem. I can keep the footer down by removing the height:100% property but then my semi transparent background doesn't push down to the footer when viewed with a large enough width. In it's current form it works properly when viewed full screen but once the width gets too narrow the content runs behind the footer. You can view it here... codykrauskopf.com/about or http://jsfiddle.net/73PHQ/

Would it just be easier for me to use javascript to dynamically set the height of the page?

```
html, body {height: 100%;
width:100%;
margin:0;
padding:0;
overflow:auto;
}

#wrap {
width:100%;
min-height:100%;
}
/* Circus.html content*/
#circusContent{
margin-left:100px;

}

p{
font-family:georgia;

}

div.topButtons{
display:inline-block;
margin-top:15px;
line-height:50px;
text-align:center;
vertical-align:middle;
width:130px;
background: rgb(166, 166, 166); /* The Fallback */
background: rgba(166, 166, 166, .5); 
}

a.forms{
text-decoration:underline;
}

div.topButtons:hover{
background: rgb(100, 0, 0); /* The Fallback */
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1); 
}

#circusParagraph{

color:white;
font-size:14px;
text-align:center;
margin-left:10%;
width:70%;
}
/* road show page specific styling */

.rs{
width:200px;
height:200px;
}

/* museum page specific styling */
#museumPic{
height:400px;
width:520px;
margin-left:-50px;
}

/* acts page specific styling */
p.acts{
text-align:left;
}




/* ticket page specific styling */


div.ticketBut{
display:inline-block;
margin-top:15px;
font-size:20px;
line-height:20px;
text-align:center;
vertical-align:middle;
width:250px;
background: rgb(166, 166, 166); /* The Fallback */
background: rgba(166, 166, 166, .5);
}
div.ticketBut:hover{
background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* The Fallback */
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}


/* about page specific styling */
#float{
float:right;
}
#floatleft{
float:left;
}
/* membership page specific styling */
#leftJustified{
text-align:left;
}
/* festival page specific styling */
#leftFestivalButton{
margin-left:138px;
}
/* performers page specific styling */



h3{
margin-top:0px;
padding-top:4px;
text-align:center;
font-size:23px;
font-family:Gill Sans MT Condensed;
font-weight:normal;
margin-bottom:0px;
color:#DEB887;
}


div.buttons{
background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* The Fallback */
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
width:100%;

height:4.057017%;
text-align:center;
vertical-align:middle;
}
p.buttons{
display:inline;
font-family:Gill Sans MT Condensed;
font-size:25px;
}

div.buttons:hover{
background: rgb(100, 0, 0); /* The Fallback */
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1); 
}

div.notPage{
width:100%;
height:4.057017%;
text-align:center;
vertical-align:middle;
}
div.notPage:hover{
background: rgb(100, 0, 0); /* The Fallback */
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1); 
}
img{
border:0;
}
a{
text-decoration:none;
font-family: Lucida Bright;
color:white;
border:none;
border:0;
}

/* Home page bottom opaque bar */
#bottomSideBar{
background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* The Fallback */
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
width:100%;

height:39.58333333%;
margin-bottom:-30px;
}

#sidebar{
background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* The Fallback */
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
width:100%;
height:27.9605263157%;

}

#logo{
width:100%;
}
#bank{
position:absolute;
bottom:35px;
left:0px;
}

#main {
     /* must be same height as the footer */
    max-width:120em;
    }  

#side{position:relative;
float:left;
width:22.513089005%;
height:100%;
}

#footer {position: relative;
    margin-top: -35px; /* negative value of footer height */
    height: 35px;
    width:100%;
    float:none;
    background-color:black;
    color:white;

    } 

#foottext{
margin:0;
padding-top:8px;
}

#content{
position:relative;
margin-left:22.513089005%;
margin-bottom:-35px;
width:77.486910998%;
background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* The Fallback */
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
}

table{
font-family:georgia;
}
.tickets{
border:1px solid #DEB887;
border-collapse:collapse;
padding:5px;
}
#tickets{
border:1px solid #DEB887;
border-collapse:collapse;
margin: 0 auto;
}


/*Opera Fix*/
body:before {
    content:"";
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    width:0;
    margin-top:-32767px;
}

/* slideshow css*/

#coin-slider{
border:2px solid white;
margin-top:10px;

}
.coin-slider { overflow: hidden; zoom: 1; position: relative; }
.coin-slider a{ text-decoration: none; outline: none; border: none; }

.cs-buttons { font-size: 0px; padding: 10px; float: left; }
.cs-buttons a { margin-left: 5px; height: 10px; width: 10px; float: left; border: 1px solid #B8C4CF; color: #B8C4CF; text-indent: -1000px; }
.cs-active { background-color: #B8C4CF; color: #FFFFFF; }

.cs-title { width: 545px; padding: 10px; background-color: #000000; color: #FFFFFF; }

.cs-prev, 
.cs-next { background-color: #000000; color: #FFFFFF; padding: 0px 10px; }


#main,
#wrap,
#content,
#circusContent{
height:100%;

}
```

Comment: Can you provide the HTML as well? A codepen, jsfiddle is much easier to get the full picture.

Comment: jsfiddle added for your convenience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cleaned up your CSS a little. 
To achieve the sticky footer you can do this a lot easier. There were a lot of styles which added complexity to achieve basically the same thing.

Note: The goal was a sticky footer and 100% height backgrounds on the left column and content column (which has a double background to overlay the background with a transparent background color)

References worth a read:
http://css-tricks.com/stacking-order-of-multiple-backgrounds/

```
html,body
{
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0
}

#wrap
{
  min-height:100%;
  position:relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#wrap:before
{
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  left: 22.5131%;
  position:absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 77.4869%;
  background: url(http://24ari923j4ns2i5id6kb6bqt7v.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Big-Apple-Circus-The-Tutu-Project-Group-Shot.jpg) no-repeat;
  z-index: -1;
}
#wrap:before
{
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  left: 22.5131%;
  position:absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 77.4869%;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0.5))), url(http://24ari923j4ns2i5id6kb6bqt7v.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Big-Apple-Circus-The-Tutu-Project-Group-Shot.jpg) no-repeat;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 100%), url(http://24ari923j4ns2i5id6kb6bqt7v.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Big-Apple-Circus-The-Tutu-Project-Group-Shot.jpg) no-repeat;
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 100%), url(http://24ari923j4ns2i5id6kb6bqt7v.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Big-Apple-Circus-The-Tutu-Project-Group-Shot.jpg) no-repeat;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 100%), url(http://24ari923j4ns2i5id6kb6bqt7v.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Big-Apple-Circus-The-Tutu-Project-Group-Shot.jpg) no-repeat;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#80000000', endColorstr='#80000000',GradientType=1 );
  z-index: -2;
}
#content {
  padding-bottom: 5em; /* level out negative margin footer */
}

#footer
{
  position:relative;
  margin:-3em 0 0;
  height:3em;
  width:100%;
  float:none;
  background-color:#000;
  color:#fff;
  clear:both;
}
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/2Ddzd/22/
http://fiddle.jshell.net/2Ddzd/22/show/

Comment: If you don't mind can you explain what exactly I did that was messing this up? Also, thank you.

Comment: Also, this fixed the footer but now my semi transparent background doesn't go down to the footer. http://jsfiddle.net/N7zFY/15/

Comment: Basically it was a combination of not clearing the footer, setting overflow, margins, negative margins, ... In that sense difficult to pin-point.

Comment: semi transparent background? Can you explain what it should do? Is the circus like background image?

Comment: I would like for that "background" if you will to extend all the way down to the footer regardless of if there is content to force it down that far. I think it looks like shyyt if it only goes down as far as the content. Check codykrauskopf.com/about if you want a visual.

Comment: You put the background in my jsfiddle on the #wrap container to do this.

Comment: @Cody Krauskopf use `overflow:hidden;` for `#wrap`

Comment: Exaxtly that was missing to contain the floats: http://fiddle.jshell.net/N7zFY/18/show/

Comment: @sigma I only want that background on the main content portion not on the buttons but I want the transparent background to extend to the footer regardless of content height. So the left side(buttons) you can see clearly to the background image and the right side(content) is semi transparent for the full height and width regardless of content height and width. does that make sense?

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/N7zFY/22/show - Your left column repeating background you can do the same technique sort of.

Comment: We're not on the same page. That green shit I only put in there so you could see the text go behind the footer. Apologies. This is what it should look like http://s28.postimg.org/an57gscn1/image.png

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/Nj2r4/4/ - the green background-color does not matter (removed it). Used two similar images to illustrate the technique. http://fiddle.jshell.net/Nj2r4/4/show/

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/57nebjgp1/  The gap here is what I'm talking about. I don't want that gap there.

Comment: What gap do you mean? The dark transparent background over the content background?

Comment: Why not apply the background transparency on the background-image (photoshop) and remove it from #content?

Comment: The only way I see is to apply multiple backgrounds where one would be a lineair gradient (from black to black) with transparency.

Comment: No worries ... 
I would also make your navigation more semantic. http://css-tricks.com/navigation-in-lists-to-be-or-not-to-be/

Answer (score 0):

You can use absolute positioning to "glue" a footer to the bottom of the page.

`#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Remove `height:100%` for `#wrap` and add min-height as below

```
#wrap{
    min-height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

To make the footer sticky to the bottom add this to your stylesheet

```
#footer{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    margin-top:0;
}
```